# CakePHP 3 - How to identify the installed behaviors in a model when baking a controller

Tags: cakephp, console, behavior

I'd like to adapt my controller baking code (vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Template/Bake/Template/Bake/Controller/controller.ctp) so when baking a controller it will automatically detect if there is a (f.e. Translate-) behavior installed in the model and add "use Cake\I18n\I18n;" to the controller while baking it.

So, can anyone tell me how to identify the installed behaviors within the controller-baking-code?

Comment: Are you aware that this would only work with table classes that already exists when baking the controller? Also do you know that you should create custom bake templates in your apps template structure? It reads as if you are about to modify vendor files.

Comment: Yes, I know I need to create the custom bake templates in src/Template/Bake. That's what I'm doing already.

Comment: When I create new tables with translated fields I add the translated fields as 'i18n_fieldName'. In Model and Entity baking files I check for fields with 'i18n_' and adapt the code automatically to add the Translate behaviour. I also want to do that in the Controller baking file: I should add "use Cake\I18n\I18n;" in the Controller when there are fields with 'i18n_' or when there is a Translate behavior in the Model... When baking the Model you can check the $validation array for 'i18n_...' fields but apparently the $validation array is not available in the Controller baking file?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the table class already exists when baking the controller, you should be able to get the required information from [**`$modelObj`**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/master/src/Shell/Task/ControllerTask.php#L121-L127) that is passed to the view, it's an instance of the table class that is associated with the controller.

The behavior registry available via `Table::behaviors()` should have the info that you need.

```
$modelObj->behaviors()->has('Translate')
```

And of course you can get further information from the table, like the schema (`Table::schema()`), validation rules (`Table::validator()`), etc...

See also

- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::behaviors()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_behaviors)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\BehaviorRegistry::has()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.BehaviorRegistry.html#_has)**

Comment: Thanks! if ($modelObj->behaviors()->has('Translate')) { does the trick!